# How can I fix set-location command in PowerShell

Tags: python, powershell, path

I've been having  problem with "Path" VSCode , I watched some tutorials about it, then I tried to change the path through PowerShell, with Set-Location command. As you can see below:
[image]

Trying to change in PowerShell, i closed and opened the windows , but didn't work:
[image]

Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: You say you've uninstalled Anaconda. It sounds like its initialization command is still in your `$PROFILE` file, which causes the error. Remove this command from `$PROFILE`.